# java.lang.ClassCastException androidx.viewpager.widget.Viewpager cannot be cast to CustomPager

Tags: android, kotlin

I wanted to use a viewpager that dynamically adjusts the height, so I created a custompager and tried to build it, but I got the following error.
Error caused by     at.ViewPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(ViewPagerAdapter.kt:34)
at.CustomPager.onMeasure(CustomPager.kt:22)
Anyone can help?

Below is my code where the error occurred.

```
class CustomPager : ViewPager {
    private var mCurrentView: View? = null

    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context!!) {}
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(
        context!!,
        attrs
    ) {
    }

    public override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        var heightMeasureSpec = heightMeasureSpec
        if (mCurrentView == null) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
            return
        }
        var height = 0
        mCurrentView!!.measure(
            widthMeasureSpec,
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                0,
                MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED
            )
        )
        val h = mCurrentView!!.measuredHeight
        if (h > height) height = h
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
            height,
            MeasureSpec.EXACTLY
        )
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
    }

    fun measureCurrentView(currentView: View?) {
        mCurrentView = currentView
        requestLayout()
    }

    fun measureFragment(view: View?): Int {
        if (view == null) return 0
        view.measure(0, 0)
        return view.measuredHeight
    }
}
```

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

    private val mFragmentList: ArrayList<Fragment> = ArrayList()
    private val mFragmentTitleList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    private var mCurrentPosition = -1

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return mFragmentTitleList[position]
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return mFragmentList[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
       return mFragmentList.size
    }

    override fun setPrimaryItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, `object`)

        if (position != mCurrentPosition) {
            val fragment = `object` as Fragment?
            val pager = container as CustomPager
            if (fragment != null && fragment.view != null) {
                mCurrentPosition = position
                pager.measureCurrentView(fragment.view)
            }
        }

    }

    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment)
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This type-cast is wrong: `container as CustomPager`; because it's a `ViewPager`.

Most likely you're not inflating any `CustomPager` in XML.

Comment: I already add custompager to xml instead of viewpager.